# Add in drop down menu to existing navigation menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an existing HTML menu which I need to add further navigation to. I have added in the extra `<ul>` and `<li>` tags which I believe are in the correct place. I also have some CSS but ti appears to mess up the links on the nav bar.

Here is an image of what it currently looks like:

http://gyazo.com/b45d1a07de57e617715b74ced91b942b

This is what it like before I added the code for the dropdown menu:

http://gyazo.com/d3dcd6b866187a650f83842beeb0be0d

HTML

```
<!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->

<div id="nav_bar">                                           

<ul>

<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<li><a href="info.html">INFO</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<ul>

<li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - SURVIVAL</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - PURE-PVP</a></li> `enter code here`
<li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - GAMESWORLD</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp; 

</ul> 

</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav_bar {
         background-color:#a22b2f;
         padding-top:10px; 
         height:35px;
         box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
         }

#nav_bar ul {
            margin:-15px; 
            margin-left:110px;            
            }

#nav_bar ul li {
               display:inline;              
               }

#nav_bar ul li ul {
                  opacity:0;
                  }

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
                        opacity:1;                        
                        }

#nav_bar a:link { 
                text-decoration: none;
                }

#nav_bar a:visited {
               color:#ffffff;
               }

#nav_bar a:hover {
                 background:#8c1b1f;
                 padding-bottom:12px;
                 padding-top:16px;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right:10px;                               
                 }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to completely remove your CSS with the exception of the styles which you had applied to `#nav_bar` and cleaned up your HTML structure as well by removing all the `&nbsp`'s.

```css
#nav_bar {
  background-color: #a22b2f;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
}
#nav_bar ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#nav_bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav_bar ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
}
#nav_bar ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - SURVIVAL</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - PURE-PVP</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - GAMESWORLD</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can style it further as per your needs.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thanks a lot mate. I'm sort of new to web design.

Comment: @Grant You're welcome, mate. You can style the dropdown menu as well using CSS to match the overall style of your website. Please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: How do I mark your answer? I'm completely new to this site.

Comment: @Grant There would be an outline of a tick-mark appearing next to my answer at the top, simply click on that. Also, you can go to this link and get familiar with using Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Can I ask you another question related to creating a hover effect?

Comment: Sure, I'll keep an eye on that.

Comment: @Grant Just answered it.